# How to add line-spacing between two <li>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an unordered list in my one of the page which is designed using Twitter Bootstrap.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled col-md-5   col-md-offset-3">
 <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>Link1</li>
 <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>Link2</li>
 <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>Link3</li>
 <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>Link4</li>
</ul>
```

How can I add line-spacing between those li tags?

Comment: So what’s the actual problem …? Write a rule that applies a margin or padding, depending on what specific effect you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add margin to all li elements but not the last one.

```
ul > li + li {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: if that helped you, please accept the answer

Comment: Hey its really helped... why downvote? @downvoter can you explain here...

Comment: Also make sure to use an id or class for the <ul>, because the code above will impact all <ul> elements.

Comment: no need there is only one ul element in this page... thanks anyway.